# How to understand "wincing as they felt their raw pink faces" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Harry noticed too that the castle seemed to be undergoing an extra-thorough cleaning. Several grimy portraits had been scrubbed, much to the displeasure of their subjects, who sat huddled in their frames muttering darkly and **wincing as they felt their raw pink faces**.

I don't quite get the last part of the sentence "wincing as they felt their raw pink faces" in this context. Is it because they had their faces scrubbed, so their faces went pink and they were wincing? How should we understand it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The sentence is actually somewhat redundant; one does not need to use both **raw** and **pink** together, since one is a reference to the other.

**Rubbed raw** is an idiom referring to skin that has been rubbed or cleaned until it hurts, normally by somebody else. It's commonly heard in reference to a parent cleaning their child, especially in earlier centuries when such cleaning might have been done with a stiff brush and harsh soap.  You might also use it to refer to the painful skin around the nose when one has a cold and has been rubbing one's nose with tissues a lot.

The term comes from the mild inflammation of the skin that comes when it has been rubbed in this way - it resembles raw meat. That's why I say that **raw pink faces** is somewhat redundant, since **raw** implies **pink**. Still, it works for the rhythm and effect of the sentence.

So, the portraits have been scrubbed clean, probably with a stiff-bristled brush, and thus the skin on their faces is painful and pink; they are touching their faces with their hands - implied by **felt** - and wincing with the pain.

Comment: A specious notion that redundancy is to be avoided in all cases has entered the consciousness of  many contributors to this site. But +1 for the last paragraph.
 https://www.google.com/search?q=%22raw%20pink%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en